# How do I multiple individual time-series data to train a LSTM model?

Tags: keras, pandas, lstm, rnn

I have 100 univariate time-series from individual patients measuring glucose levels. Each time-series is ~20k. I need to train my LSTM model using all of the data.

I don't think concatenating all into one single long time-series makes sense since all are individually collected independent of each other.

Can someone please help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Forecasting? Time series classification?

Comment: its a forecasting task. all values are numeric. data has been collected from individual patients.

Comment: And you are trying to create a single model that makes a prediction for a generic patient?

Comment: yes. since I will have at max 25k observations for an individual patient. i want to train over my entire dataset with over 100 patients. this will allow me a generic model which can be applied for prediction over any of the patients.

Comment: @bapowell can i use an variable with ID for each of the patient time-series?

Comment: Sorry, last question: what is the use-case?  You get a new patient and some data on this patient, and you wish to predict future levels for this patient?  Why not just build a model on a per-patient basis?  The LSTM will learn the patterns of a single time series.

Comment: @bapowell if we look at per-patient data we have very less data to train an LSTM. that is why i am trying to build a model which will be generalizable enough even for a new entrant.

Comment: You can absolutely train an LSTM on a single time series with 20K time steps; many fewer, actually.